# Animate CC Canvas: Variable not printing in Console

Tags: variables, height, width, animate-cc, create.js

so I am using Animate CC outputting to Canvas, and have the following in my script:

```
var width = canvas.width; 
var height = canvas.height;

console.log(width, height);
```

Question: When I open the console in the preview window and type in "canvas.width" or canvas.height it returns the correct values. However the console.log doesn't print the variable values. Any ideas what I am missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: If I add just your code in a empty Animate project (without adding any elements), and I test it, in the console it outputs both values. The same goes for the HTML/JS generated from that proyect.

Comment: Interesting. Looks like it doesn't print in Firefox, but in Chrome it does indeed print the variable. Any workaround for this? Thanks

Comment: It's weird it doesn't print on Firefox. In my case it does. Have you checked the [toolbar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Console_messages#Filtering_by_category) in the console in the Firefox Developer Tools? Your console log should be in the Logging category.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the scope but maybe try
`console.log(this.width, this.height);`
or

```
this.width = width;
this.height = height;

console.log(this.width, this.height);
```

Only because I know `Create.js` has a scope limiter to try and keep locals local.
Just guessing but hope it works